# C++ passing const string references in methods?

Tags: c++, methods, constants

I'm trying to initialize a private variable of my Class passing a const string &aString to it as parameter.

Here's my method:

```
void Image::initWithTextureFile(const std::string &inTextureName)
{   
    Texture2D *imTexture = TEXTURE_MANAGER->createTexture(inTextureName);

    if(imTexture)
    {
        texture = imTexture;
        scale = 1.0f;
        name = inTextureName; //name is a private string variable inside my class
        initImplementation();
    }else {
        printf("Could not load texture when creating Image from file %s\n",inTextureName.c_str());
    }
}
```

My problem is the following, when I call this method I do it like:

```
myInitializer.initWithTextureFile("myFile.bmp");
```

When I'm inside the scope of `initWithTextureFile` the `name` variable takes the value of `inTextureName`. For this example if I `cout << name << endl;` inside `initWithTextureFile` i would get `"myFile.bmp"`

But when I leave the scope of the function, `name` looses it's value, so when i `cout << name << endl;` I get nothing printed in the console.

Could anyone point me out to what's going on here?

Name is declared:

```
private:
    std::string name;
```

Comment: Not enough code to answer the question. Look for local 'name' variable hiding one in the enclosing scope (class member, global variable).

Comment: It would help to see the declaration for name.  Also, check to see if initImplmentation() does anything to name.

Comment: I just added the name variable declaration.

Comment: Are you printing inside other methods of Image class? "name" should not be visible outside of Image methods, so cout << name << endl should fail to compile.

Comment: Please excuse tge silly question:
Are you doing "cout << name << endl;" or are you doing "cout << myInitializer.name << endl;"?

name is private, but you should at least be able to see it's value within a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're outside the class scope, and `cout << name` compiles at all, it means you have another variable named `name`, and that's what's being picked up.  If you want to refer to it outside the class, you'll have to come up with a way that will export it.  You might, for example, have a member function like `const std::string &GetName() { return name; }`.

Comment: @MrGando indicated that he is accessing name outside of the the function scope, not outside the class scope.

Answer (score 3):

You either omitting something in your description or are not showing appropriate code that could help solve your problem.

This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    void f(const string& str) { name = str; }
    void g() { cout << name << endl; }

    string name;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.f("test");
    a.g();
}
```

Output:

```
test
```

Comment: Why is const required, since const means 'this value will not change'?   (I tested without it and got a Linker: Unresolved External error, so I know it is required - I just don't understand Why)

Answer (score 1):

That should work.  Are you sure it is not being modified somewhere else, such as in initImplementation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably have to do with the name variable : is it a pointer or ref to string instead of a plain string ?

Comment: just added the declaration of name.

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable explanation here is that you must be working with two different `name` objects. The one you declared as a class member should hold its value when you exit the method. It is just that outside the class method you must be printing a completely different `name`, which is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say something about short-lived stack objects but I realised that was wrong.  What it could be is something to do with exporting the containing class from a DLL.

If so, you might find a warning like this:

```
c:\yourclass.h(7): warning C4251: 'YourClass::name_' : class 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'YourClass'
```

[This thread](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/VC-Language/30952961/a-solution-to-warning-c4251--class-needs-to-have-dllinterface.aspx) describes more.

Answer (score -1):

How is 'name' declared? It seems like maybe it's declared as a reference instead of an object.

Comment: What difference would it make? The above assignment should copy the value to whatever that reference is attached to.

Comment: Maybe my C++ is too rusty. But if you do: "std::string& name; name = inTextureName;" and then inTextureName goes out of scope, won't name be pointing at something random on the stack?

Comment: @Moishe: There's no way to say what will hapen because yor code is invalid. In C++ you can't define a reference without initializing it. I.e. you can just define `std::string& name`. It simply won't compile.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
name = std::string(inTextureName);
```

Comment: The take a look at initImplementation and verify that it's not overwriting name.  The code you posted *should* work; I've seen weirdness like you describe with some compilers/libraries that have a buggy reference-counted string implementation, but usually an explicit instantiation fixes that.